# How to use private and public routes in api-platform of single resource

Tags: api-platform.com

i'l try to use different routes in a resource and setup severall firewalls:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    api_login:
        pattern: ^/api/public/authentication
        anonymous: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        stateless: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/public/authentication_token
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
#            guard:
#                authenticators:
#                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    api_private:
        pattern: ^/api/private
        stateless: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator


access_control:
    - { path: ^/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI
    - { path: ^/api/public/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/private/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

And want in my User-Resource to use different route_prefixes. in my case, i wan't for the collectionOperation.get to match the public firewall.
try'd to set globally for this resource the */private* prefix und want to overwrite in collectionOperation.get:

```
/**
* @ApiResource(
*     routePrefix="/private",
*     collectionOperations={
*         "get"={
*             "path"="/api/public/users",
*             "security"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"
*     },
*     }
* )
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
*/
```

but when i use *path*, the prefix is not overwritten:

```
/api/private/api/public/users
```

should i don't use "route_prefix" and define for each action a custom-path?

Answer (score 0):

Full resource path is concatenation `api_platform.prefix` (`config/routes/api_platform.yaml`), [routePrefix](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#prefixing-all-routes-of-all-operations) and `path`.

I think more flexible is open all API resources at firewall level and close some resources/operations via [security annotations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/).